# Why a navigation bar button item doesn't work when the textview has been resignedFirstResponder()?

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextview, uibarbuttonitem, first-responder

Here is an odd one. I have two bar button items, one is cancel and one is done. The done button saves the text in the textview in the coreData and then pops the current view from the navigationController and goes to previous viewcontroller. The cancel button just goes to the previous controller. The whole thing works when the textview is the firstResponder() or the keyboard is up. When the keyboard resigns as the firstResponder, both buttons don't work. As in the just don't do anything. Done button doesn't save the text nor it takes me to previous viewcontroller.

Here is the code for both the buttons:

Done button:

```
 @objc func handleDoneButton() {
    print("hello")
    if edittaskview.text.isEmpty == true
    {
        moContext.delete(editnotes!)
    }
    else
    {
        editnotes?.sNote = edittaskview.text
    }
    var error: NSError?
    do {
        // Save The object

        try moContext.save()
        print("SAVED")
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)


}
```

Cancel button:

```
 @objc func handleCancelButton()
{
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Again, the code in both these functions work when the buttons are tapped only when the textview is the first responder otherwise they don't.

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

 class editViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
UITextViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
 var editnotes: addednotes?
var prioritynumber: Int = 1
let moContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! 
AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var colorArray = [prioritylevels]()
lazy var edittaskview: UITextView = {
    let textview = UITextView()
    textview.isScrollEnabled = false
    textview.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    textview.backgroundColor = .white
    textview.delegate = self

    return textview
}()
var clearview: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    //view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return view
}()
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDoneButton))
let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancelButton))

lazy var priorityCV: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self

    return cv
}()

let line: UIView = {
    let line = UIView()
    return line
}()

let reminderView: UIView = {
   let reminder = UIView()
    reminder.backgroundColor = .white
    return reminder
}()

let reminderTitle: UILabel = {
   let title = UILabel()
    title.text = "Due Date"
    title.textColor = .black
    title.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 16)
    title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

    return title
}()
let reminderMsg: UILabel = {
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = "No Due Date Set"
    title.textColor = .black
  //  title.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 12)
    title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    return title
}()
let reminderAddBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("Set", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSetReminderBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

var textHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    adjustTextViewHeight()
}
 let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.97, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    //ColorArray for PriorityCV
    colorArray = [prioritylevels(color: UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.78, blue:0.73, alpha:1.0), name: "   Low", prioritynumber: 1), prioritylevels(color: UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.78, blue:0.35, alpha:1.0), name: "Medium", prioritynumber: 2),prioritylevels(color: UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.63, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0), name: "  High", prioritynumber: 3), prioritylevels(color: UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.28, blue:0.70, alpha:1.0), name: "Urgent", prioritynumber: 4)]



    priorityCV.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cvid")

    navigationItem.title = "Edit Task"
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
    view.addSubview(clearview)
    clearview.addSubview(line)
    clearview.addSubview(edittaskview)
    clearview.addSubview(priorityCV)
    clearview.addSubview(reminderView)
    reminderView.addSubview(reminderTitle)
    reminderView.addSubview(reminderMsg)
    reminderView.addSubview(reminderAddBtn)
    edittaskview.text = editnotes?.sNote
    edittaskview.becomeFirstResponder() //taskview becomes first responder here when the view is loaded. 
//        view.addSubview(datePicker)


    setupViews()
    line.backgroundColor = editnotes?.sPriorityColor

    let dismissbytap =  UITapGestureRecognizer()
    dismissbytap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDismissByTap))
    dismissbytap.delegate = self
    clearview.addGestureRecognizer(dismissbytap) //a clear uiview is added behind all the subviews.  this uiview is used to dismiss keyboard when tapped on it.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return colorArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cvid", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row].color
    let prioritylabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 20, y: 0, width: view.frame.width / 4, height: 30))

    cell.addSubview(prioritylabel)
    prioritylabel.text = colorArray[indexPath.row].name
    prioritylabel.textColor = .white
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 4, height: 30)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    prioritynumber = colorArray[indexPath.row].prioritynumber
    line.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row].color
    editnotes?.sPriorityColor = colorArray[indexPath.row].color
    editnotes?.sPriorityNumber = prioritynumber
    print(prioritynumber)
}
func setupViews()
{
   _ = edittaskview.anchor(line.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 2, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    self.edittaskview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 8, 4, 8)

    self.textHeightConstraint = edittaskview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
    self.textHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
    self.adjustTextViewHeight()
    _ = clearview.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
  _ = priorityCV.anchor(edittaskview.bottomAnchor, left: clearview.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: clearview.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 30)
  _ = line.anchor(clearview.topAnchor, left: clearview.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: clearview.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 4)

  _ = reminderView.anchor(priorityCV.bottomAnchor, left: clearview.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 30, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 60)
    _ = reminderTitle.anchor(reminderView.topAnchor, left: reminderView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 8, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 100, heightConstant: 20)
    _ = reminderMsg.anchor(reminderTitle.bottomAnchor, left: reminderView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 4, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 100, heightConstant: 24)
    _ = reminderAddBtn.anchor(reminderView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: reminderView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 32, widthConstant: 30, heightConstant: 20)
}

@objc func handleDoneButton() {
    print("hello")

    if edittaskview.text.isEmpty == true
    {
        moContext.delete(editnotes!)
    }
    else
    {
        editnotes?.sNote = edittaskview.text
    }
    var error: NSError?
    do {
        // Save The object

        try moContext.save()
        print("SAVED")
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)


}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.adjustTextViewHeight()
}


func adjustTextViewHeight() {
    let fixedWidth = edittaskview.frame.size.width

    let newSize = edittaskview.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    self.textHeightConstraint?.constant = newSize.height + 15

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}


@objc func handleCancelButton()
{
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}


@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let componenets = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: sender.date)
    if let day = componenets.day, let month = componenets.month, let year = componenets.year, let hour = componenets.hour, let minute = componenets.minute  {
        print("\(day) \(month) \(year) \(hour) \(minute)")
    }
}

@objc func handleDismissByTap() {
    edittaskview.resignFirstResponder() // Resigning textview as first responder


}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
   return touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view
}
```

Comment: weird . check your  views hierarchy.... there not be no connection between the TextView  and the Buttons (unless you disabled them manually).

Comment: these are navigation bar buttons. And yeah there is no connection between these two things. no idea what's the issue!

Comment: how can a user dismiss the keyboard in your app ?

Comment: Tapping anywhere outside the textview.

Comment: It might help if you include the code where the text view resigns first responder.

Comment: Just added the whole code. Take a look at it please.

Comment: can you tell us if the `handleDoneButton` handler gets called at all? sis the problem that the handler does not get called (so "hello" is not printed), or it is called, just the it does not perform what you expect ("hello" gets printed, but view controller will not get dismissed)?

Comment: handleDoneButton function gets called and "hello" is printed as well as viewcontroller is dismissed. But this only works when  the textview is firstresponder. If the textview is resigned then nothing works. "Hello" is not printed and the view controller is also not dismissed. Same with cancel button.

Comment: @TomHarrington Just added the whole code in the post. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This does seem odd - and I don't know *why* the navigation bar buttons are only calling the functions when your text view is active, but...

One way around it is to move your right and left `UIBarButtonItem` declarations into `viewDidLoad()` instead of at the class level.

As an aside, you'll get a better animation and keyboard appearance if you move `edittaskview.becomeFirstResponder()` from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewDidAppear()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how but instead of creating bar buttons seperately and then assigning them like so `self.navigationBarItem.leftbarbutton = leftBarbutton`
I decided to construct them using UIBarButtonItem constructor.

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancelButton))`

It worked!

Pretty odd to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do as well is making the declaration of your `UIBarButtonItem` a `lazy var`.

It's getting instantiated with the class. If you make it a `lazy var` it will get created when you need to use it. If you want to keep it a `let` and at class level, just do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourBarButtonItem.target = self
}
```

Either of these methods will keep the target intact. I was having this same issue.

It's still a weird issue and I think the compiler should yell at you for trying to use self before initialization. It does so when you put `self()` instead.